# Fanbox featureLoader script not found

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been using the legacy Featureloader.js.php script for some time now without any problems at :

https://ssl.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php

For some reason this server seems to have stopped responding in the last day or so - i get a server not found response in Chrome developer tools -

We want to continue to use the Fanbox plugin, as it allows us to style the returned content appropriate to our site - the new likebox doesnt have that option

Wondered if anyone knew why that server is currently not responding, and whether it's simply a temporary problem or might be a permanent issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Facebook blog:

> Removing FeatureLoader JavaScript SDK. As part of the OAuth2 migration, we announced that the FeatureLoader SDK is no longer supported as of October 1st, 2011. On February 1st 2012, we will remove FeatureLoader. Please ensure that your app is using the JS SDK.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/638/ (under "Upcoming Breaking Changes on February 1st 2012")

Comment: Thanks Plamena - i'll have a look at the JS SDK instead